# @Transactional not working when using try catch block

Tags: spring, transactions

The transactional roll back is not working when the exception is caught on the catch block, and another method is called for throw the exception. The pseudo code for the above is:

```
@Transactional(rollBackFor = Exception.class)
public void method1() {

  // Calling another method
  method2();

}

private void method2() {

  try {

    dbOperation1();

  } catch (Exception e) {

    handleFault()

  }
}

handleFault() {
  // Calling another method and throwing an exception
  throwException()

}

throwException() {
  //....

  throw new Exception();

}
```

Comment: since you are catching your exception on `method2()`, `method1()` will never throws an exception.  If exception is not thrown in the method where you specifies `rollBackFor = Exception.class` it will not rollback.  For `method1()`, there is no exception.

Comment: Please show the real code.